# SQL SELECT statement based on the fields selected on the checklistbox

Tags: sql, arrays, delphi-2010, dbgrid, checklistbox

I'm trying to use SQL to display fields which the user selects in a `TCheckListBox` onto a `TDBGrid`.

I thought arrays may help. Here's my code, it doesn't execute:

```
Var

arrFields : array [1..9] of string = ('UserId','Surname','Name','EMail',
  'Gender','DOB','ContinentOfOririn','Passport','IDNumber');
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmUsersMan.pnlDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
I: Integer;
arrTempArray: Array [1..10] of String;
begin

for i := 0 to chkDisplay.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if chkDisplay.Checked[i] then
      arrTempArray[i+1]:='Checked';

    With dmTourists  do
      begin
        qryUsers.Active:=False;
        qryUsers.SQL.Clear;
        qryUsers.SQL.Add('SELECT ''arrFileds[i]'' FROM tblUsers WHERE ''(arrTemp[i+1]=Checked)''');
        qryUsers.Active:=True;
      end;
  end;

end;
End;
```

Comment: You are not populating `arrTempArray` correctly, and you are not building up the SQL correctly. It is difficult to understand whether you are trying to `SELECT` only certain fields that are checked, or whether you are trying to select all fields depending on which values selected fields contain. What is your actual goal here? Please explain.

Comment: SELECT and Display only the fields that are checked on the checkListBox